# Communication between C# and webbrowsers (without port-forwarding?)

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket, portforwarding, upnp

I have a C# application used all over the world, which essentially runs a java process. I would like to extend this program, and add a feature where people can read the process output from wherever they are using a web browser. (and possibly send input)

My first thought was a WebSocket server which would run in the C# application, and the browsers would connect to it using javascript. However that would require port forwarding on every system running the server, and I haven't found a better solution to that than NATUPnP, which fails to do it's job on a significant number of computers.

(And if that wasn't enough, I failed to create a successful connection between a C# webserver and javascript, but that's a whole other question)

So what I'm asking is:

1. Is WebSocket my best option to do this? (best meaning stable, and not too complicated to do)
2. Is there a way to bypass the port forwarding issue? And if not, do you know of any more efficient ways than NATUPnP?

Comment: The "normal" answer (used by, e.g. Nest Thermostats which is a very similar problem) is to have a cloud service that acts as a broker between the in-home server and the web-browser. So, the in-home server connects to the cloud service, and the web-browser connects to the cloud service, and now they can both talk to each other because the cloud service is acting as a proxy. Of course, someone has to then pay to run that cloud service, so it all depends on your business model.

Comment: Alternatively, you can look into STUN/TURN servers - STUN is used to negotiate a direct path between two clients that are potentially behind firewalls and NAT devices. If STUN fails to negotiate a direct path, it falls back to using a TURN server, which is essentially a relay as I've described above.

Comment: Sounds like you need to build a web service brother and call it a day.  You're essentially trying to accomplish the same things it sounds like.  What's stopping you from going that route?

Comment: What do you mean by 'build a web service'? How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

> The "normal" answer (used by, e.g. Nest Thermostats which is a very similar problem) is to have a cloud service that acts as a broker between the in-home server and the web-browser. So, the in-home server connects to the cloud service, and the web-browser connects to the cloud service, and now they can both talk to each other because the cloud service is acting as a proxy. Of course, someone has to then pay to run that cloud service, so it all depends on your business model.

As stated by RB, that's basically you're only option. There's services out there such as [`ngrok.com`](https://ngrok.com/) and [`localtunnel.me`](http://localtunnel.me) that can make port forwarding work behind a firewall / without a static IP